# Condition testing/callback mechanism

Tags: python, callback, conditional-statements

I need a simple class or function that takes a test (callable object which returns `True` or `False`) and a function to be called when the test is `True`, potentially doing the whole thing in a different thread maybe. something like this:

```
nums = []
t = TestClass(test=(lambda: len(nums) > 5),
              func=(lambda: sys.stdout.write('condition met'))

for n in range(10):
    nums.append(n)
    time.sleep(1) 

#after 6 loops, the message gets printed on screen.
```

Any help is appreciated. (Please, nothing too complicated since I am still a beginner)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the TestClass instance to automatically detect when its test condition has become true? That is, you don't want to have to do anything to tell it to check again? That's quite difficult. The only way I can think of do do it at all (using multiple threads, like you mention)  will have race conditions, since there's no guarantee that the testing thread will be activated immediately after the test becomes true for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in thinking you might need a separate thread to check a condition in the background.  In this separate thread, you also have to decide how often you want to check (there would be other ways to do this, but this way requires the least changes to the code you've shown).

My answer just uses a function, but you could easily use a class instead if you like:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys    

def myfn(test, callback):

    while not test():  # check if the first function passed in evaluates to True
        time.sleep(.001)  # we need to wait to give the other thread time to run.
    callback() # test() is True, so call callback.

nums = []

t = Thread(target=myfn, args=(lambda: len(nums) > 5, 
           lambda: sys.stdout.write('condition met')))
t.start() # start the thread to monitor for nums length changing

for n in range(10):
    nums.append(n)
    print nums  # just to show you the progress
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is actually the way I thought about, but I was worrying about performance. I guess it all depends on how often the test is made, because increasing the value of time.sleep also increases the chance of race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but I think this should help you get started.

```
def test_something(condition, action, *args, **kwargs):
  if condition():
    action(*args, **kwargs)

def print_success():
  print 'Success'

def test_one():
  return True

test_something(test_one, print_success)
```